# running script with exec command from grunt

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Can any explain me what does it meant by the below statement?

Use the exec command to run a Pig script with no interaction between the script and the Grunt shell (batch mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you can have a Pig script pre-written and execute it with exec.  Example taken from: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#exec

```
grunt> cat myscript.pig
a = LOAD 'student' AS (name, age, gpa);
b = LIMIT a 3;
DUMP b;

grunt> exec myscript.pig
(alice,20,2.47)
(luke,18,4.00)
(holly,24,3.27)
```

This is beneficial if you have a set of commands you run on a regular basis.  Rather then retyping it each time, you can put it in a script and run exec on it.

Comment: Thanks brandon.Could you please explain a bit on what does it meant by no interaction between script and Grunt shell.?

Comment: It means that it is parsed before execution and runs independently.  If any variables or aliases are set in the script, they are not available in the Grunt shell after execution.  No history is maintained either.  In the above example, you would not be able to access 'b'.  This is opposite of the `run` command which allows aliases / variables to be referenced afterwards.